# can't extract video from bag file

Tags: video, ros

Can't extract video from a .bag file that was recorded with an RPi camera. The idea is to be able to work with the video in another scope.

I have tried the solution from http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data
but it stops and throws :

```
REQUIRED process [rosbag-1] has died!
process has finished cleanly
log file: /user/.ros/log/8541738e-85e9-11e9-8dfb-6c8814b5a5c8/rosbag-1*.log
Initiating shutdown!
```

expected the frame%04d.jpg but it doesn't create anything!

Comment: How many frames are inside your bag?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg it has 900 frames. recorded at 30 fps. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the type of the images? Is it possible to view them using image_view?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is pretty simple, can upload the bag for me to take a look?? I can help give you a simple node in getting the data out

If you want to try it urself, follow the below guidelines.

First you have to verify the bag has valid data and valid package. Eg data not corrupted or OCV related package segfault

Second figure out the image type. is it sensor_msgs Image  or compressed image. there are a difference when converting

Third, least likely but are you sure opencv imwrite operate correctly in ROS? I had funny IO and gui error before when using my own opencv linked within ros.

**EDIT**

use the ros package  below .

https://github.com/snakehaihai/rosbag_to_video_cpp

I already created one package for you. and you video is in

https://github.com/snakehaihai/rosbag_to_video_cpp/blob/master/ros_bag_to_video_cpp/src/out.avi

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

cv::VideoWriter video_out("out.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),10, cv::Size(640,480),true);


void imagecompressedCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& msg)
{
  try
  {
    cv::Mat image = cv::imdecode(cv::Mat(msg->data),1);//convert compressed image data to cv::Mat
    cv::imshow("view", image);
    video_out.write(image);
    cv::waitKey(10);
  }
  catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("Could not convert to image!");
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "image_listener");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  cv::namedWindow("view");
  cv::startWindowThread();
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/raspicam_node/image/compressed", 1, imagecompressedCallback);
  ros::spin();
  cv::destroyWindow("view");
}
```

Comment: Sure, this is a sample video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-nh5FlZL5q9CfYFsWORPvt1UZE3ZVov0/view?usp=sharing

I am new to ROS and I could not find more help on it. The idea was to extract the images to do some preprocessing and then feed some data back to a robot. Probably there is an easier way to do this... 

by the way, when following the wiki tutorial mentioned above :
rosmake: error: no such option: --rosdep-install
I am using Kinetic but there is no info on the upgrade for this command. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Just saw it. your image is compressed format. I think thats why you did not get it right. I`ll prep a script and send here later

Comment: see changes , video is in the link.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you !

Comment: ROS does not provide all custom methods. so in future, you probably have to figure the method yourself.